# cross-validation and test-set: variance estimate

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, train-test-split

i am confused at how to estimate the variance of a classifier. Currently, i have split my data into training and test sets and used the training data with a k-fold cross-validation strategy to get the best model.

Then, i could use the whole training set to train the selected model and then evaluate the test set, but i can't find it very informative, because if gives no variance estimate of the model !?

So, how is the variance usually estimated ? maybe another k-fold cross-validation on the whole data set ? but in that case, it seems to me that the original test set from the original split was just never used and therefore useless.